# Как сделать слушатели событий клавиш вне моего приложения?

Tags: java, javafx

Имеется оконное приложение(автокликер), как сделать так, чтобы оно слушало мои события нажатия клавиш вне окна приложения (на уровне ОС). Например, если я открою браузер, мое приложение уже не реагирует на нажимаемые мной клавиши. 
Вот исходный код:

```
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.Slider;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.InputEvent;

public class Main extends Application {
    Stage window;
    Scene scene;
    int delayVal;
    Robot robot;
    boolean key;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        window = stage;
        window.setTitle("Автокликер");
        window.setResizable(false);
        window.getIcons().add(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("icondefault.png")));
        window.setAlwaysOnTop(true);

        Slider slider = new Slider(0, 1000, 500);
        slider.setMajorTickUnit(500);
        slider.setMinorTickCount(2);
        slider.setShowTickLabels(true);
        slider.setShowTickMarks(true);

        slider.valueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener < Number > () {
            public void changed(ObservableValue <? extends Number > observable, Number oldValue, Number newValue) {
                delayVal = newValue.intValue();

            }
        });

        GridPane.setConstraints(slider, 0, 1);

        Label chastota = new Label("Частота клика");
        Label valuedelay = new Label(Double.toString(slider.getValue()));
        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        GridPane.setConstraints(chastota, 0, 0);
        GridPane.setConstraints(valuedelay, 0, 2);
        grid.getChildren().addAll(chastota, slider, valuedelay);

        slider.valueProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            valuedelay.setText(String.valueOf(delayVal));
        });

        scene = new Scene(grid, 200, 100);
        window.setScene(scene);
        window.show();
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        scene.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler < KeyEvent > () {@Override
            public void handle(KeyEvent ke) {
                if (ke.getCode().getName().equals("F12")) {
                    key = false;
                    Thread clicking = new Thread(new Runnable() {@Override
                        public void run() {
                            while (!key) {
                                robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
                                robot.delay(delayVal);
                                robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
                                robot.delay(delayVal);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    clicking.start();
                } else if (ke.getCode().getName().equals("F11")) {
                    key = true;
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы, как мне кажется, неправильно излагаете свою проблему. По вашим старым вопросам могу предположить, что вам нужна функциональность кейлогеров. Вы хотите слушать нажатие кнопок и выполнять определённое действие, при нажатии на какую-то кнопку. Я прав?

Comment: Нет, вы не правы. Кейлогеры я уже реализовал(сегодня) на F12 цикл запускается, на F11 выключается. Я могу вам исходник дать, там если цикл запускается, то окно моего приложение становится не активным и что бы остановить цикл, мне нужно нажать на свое приложение и только потом F11, это очень неудобно.

Comment: Да, вы слушаете клики конкретного окна (вашего приложения). Это кейлоггер, но я сейчас говорю о кейлоггерах, которые слушают на уровне операционной системы. То есть абсолютно все нажатия.

Comment: Да, тогда вы правы. Мне нужно сделать так, что бы приложение слушало меня даже не в окне моего приложения

Comment: И изложите свои цели, чтобы не было недопониманий. А то решат, что хотите зловред написать :)

Comment: Ну блин, я щас так напишу, что вопрос получится как анекдот.. поправьте меня если что

Comment: Попробуйте библиотеку [JNativeHook](https://github.com/kwhat/jnativehook/releases) ([примеры использования](https://github.com/kwhat/jnativehook/wiki/Usage)). Библиотека использует JNI, но собрана для windows, linux и mac.

Answer (score 1):

Ты вешаешь лисенер на `scene`. Соответственно `scene` и будет обрабатывать нажатия на клавиатуру.

Поэтому такой лисенер тебе не подойдет для тех целей, которые ты хочешь.

И я уверен на 90%, что такое **java** тебе не позволит, т.к. все действия нажатия на клавиатуру происходят нативно, и нет обратной связи - ты не можешь узнать, что нажалась такая то кнопка, если ты ее будешь обрабатывать не сам ( т.е. если ты будешь обрабатывать события не у `scene` и подобных элементов).

Comment: Но есть же WindowListenerи там есть метод windowdisabled или это не то?

Comment: Где такой лисенер есть?

Comment: https://javaswing.wordpress.com/2009/08/13/jframe_window_listener/

Comment: Ну во первых, это swing. А во вторых, тебе этот window listener ничего не даст. А в третьих, ты его так же вешаешь на scene( в данном случае frame)

Comment: Это реализовано на swing, но это не значит что я не смогу это использовать на javafx. В любом случае, я знаю что можно сделать то что я хочу, потому что  я видел уже похожий кликер как у меня, по нему я и ориентируюсь.

Comment: И этот кликер так же написан на java? Ну тогда залезь в исходники, посмотри как там это устроено. Если найдешь как - расскажи, будет интересно